# UIAlertView causes UIButton whose position is changed at runtime to go back to original position

Tags: ios

So I have a `storyboard` with `autolayout` on (I need it for other views, not this one, but i cannot switch off autolayout for just one view). I change two UI elements' positions in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.
 Then I tap one of the UI elements, which shows an `UIAlertView`, which causes this UI element to go back to its original position (specified in storyboard). However (!) the other element stays in place. I tried to implement `UIAlertViewDelegate` to put button back(in 
– `willPresentAlertView`:

– `didPresentAlertView`:

– `alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex`:

– `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex`:

), 
but it didn't work (works in `didPresentAlertView`, but no in any dismiss ones).
Is there a way to keep the button in place and to keep the `autolayout` on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the constraint rather than the frame for the view you are moving. Add an Outlet to the constrain you want to change (x or y position), and you will need to update the constraint in your `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

When the UIAlertView is displayed, an animation occurs, which resets the frames in your view. Since you didn't change the constraint in the first place (just the view's frame), it gets brought back to the original position.

If you have a constraint:

```
// .h file

/// Hooked up to your Storyboard file
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint;

// .m file

self.myConstraint.constant = 300; //Your new position in either x or y.
```

Comment: You cannot edit constraint programmatically at runtime, can you?

Comment: Sure you can! Go look at your constraints in your Storyboard file. You can make an outlet to your code just like a label. Then take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html).